# Error: C stack usage 15924224 is too close to the limit?

Tags: r, shiny

The error comes with the following code `runApp()`. How can solve the problem and why does this error appear?

```
Error: C stack usage 15924224 is too close to the limit
```

My codes are following:

```
library(png)
library(styler)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(cli)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Installation"),
      p("Shiny is available on CRAN, so you can install it on the usual way from your R console:"),
      div("install packages('shiny')", style="color:red"),
      img(src="C:/Users/asus/Desktop/App-1/rstudio.png", height=70, width=200)
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

#define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

runApp(".")
```

If I run the code without `runApp()` it works and open the shiny app. However, if I try to open it through `runApp()` it gives the error mentioned above.

Comment: [recursion](https://www.roelpeters.be/c-stack-error-limit/), and in your case it appears you have 16G of RAM.

Comment: but why it appears when I use ```runApp()``` but not when use use  ```shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runApp(".")` would source Shiny app files under the current app folder.  It searches files named `app.R` or `ui.R`/`server.R` combined. If you have code `runApp(".")` in your file, following recursion will happen:

runApp -> source app.R -> find `runApp()` in code ->

execute `runApp` -> source app.R ->  -> find `runApp()` in code ->

execute `runApp` -> ...

One guideline is to never write `runApp` in your `app.R`. This function is only to be used on the console. Usually Shiny would return an error and prevent you to be trapped in the loop. Not sure why the error message is not given in your case.

Comment: oh I see! Amazing! It should not be in the script but in the console. Makes sense!